# ignore_user_abort going for infinite loop[

Tags: php

the main intension i am using ignore_user_abort is that m downloading an excel file which contains lot of data and taking more than 10min so in order to let download happen at backend and carry on with other process i am making use of this function
and as i am using this function first time in order to understand i have written a simple code as follows

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

echo 'Testing connection handling in PHP';

$i=1;
while($i<5)
{
    // Did the connection fail?
    if(connection_status() != CONNECTION_NORMAL)
    {   echo "connect lost";
        break;
    }
    else {
        echo "test";
        }

$i++;
}
```

but when i run this code its going for infinite loop

Comment: $i = 1 (always). This is always true: if($i<3){echo "test";}

Comment: made few changes but also its entering into infinte loop

Answer (score 0):

`while(1)` is equal to an infinite loop which is simply equivalent to `while(true)`

A `while` loop executes when the condition is true, since you have passed a true condition it never stops running.

### How to overcome ?

Pass a variable instead and assign some value to that variable such that it fails the condition.

```
$i=1;
while($i==1)
{
echo "I will execute only once";
$i=2;
}
```

Comment: plz note the above changes but also its entering infinite loop

Comment: See again , you are not making the condition to fail. put `$i=2` at before the ending brace of `while` loop.

Comment: oops sorry.. i made changes above and now it works so if in else part if i write a code for download excel file will it work in backend so i can continue with other process?

Comment: Sure why don't you give a try and let know if you face any issues.

Comment: ya will try and let u know